# Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, filesystem, fs

**SOLUCIONADO**

Soy nuevo en esto y estoy tratando de hacer un sistema sencillo usando el modulo fs de node para crear, y editar archivos y carpetas. Pero estoy teniendo el siguiente error: **"Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir"**

```
     try {
         let arrayFiles = await fs.readdir(__dirname);
         console.log(arrayFiles.includes('infoFiles'));
         if (arrayFiles.includes('infoFiles') !== true) {
             await fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'infoFiles'));
             this.findDirectory(nameDirectory);
         }
         else if (nameDirectory === 'dataClients' && arrayFiles.includes(nameDirectory) !== true) {
             await fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'infoFiles', 'dataClients'));
             return
         }
         else return arrayFiles
     } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
     }
 }
```

En teoría funciona bien, crea la carpeta infoFiles como dataClients, el tema es que cuando ejecuto nuevamente la función me tira el error del catch, en vez de retornar el arrayFiles. Lo q no entiendo es el porqué, si con los condicionales al ya estar las carpetas creadas no deberían ejecutarse los if...

Comment: El error te está indicando que el archivo que estás tratando de crear, ya existe con ese nombre.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera claro, pero no entiendo xq me tira el error, si con el condicional no debería intentar crear el archivo. Si ya existe simplemente debería de volver arrayFiles